# table pagination not working after update version 9

Tags: angular, antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

I am using nz-table tag and my table configration is as below.

```
    <nz-table #stockTable
              [nzData]="listData" nzSize="small"
              [nzLoading]="loading"
              [nzTotal]="pageTotal"
              [nzPageIndex]="pageIndex"
              [nzPageSize]="pageSize"
              [nzShowPagination]="true">
```

and not using table pagination instead using seperate pagination component like below

```
    <nz-pagination (nzPageIndexChange)="pageIndexChanged($event)" (nzPageSizeChange)="pageSizeChanged($event)"
                   [nzPageIndex]="pageIndex" [nzPageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                   [nzPageSize]="pageSize" [nzTotal]="pageTotal" [nzShowTotal]="totalTemplate"
                   class="pagination" nzShowQuickJumper
                   nzShowSizeChanger>
      <ng-template #totalTemplate let-total> Toplam {{ total }} stok bulunmaktadır.</ng-template>
    </nz-pagination>
```

after update to version 9 ng-zorro. nz-pagination started not to work as before on version 8
when press the second page that nz-pagination show data is coming from the API but page not refreshing. All data is belong to page 1

I have also added pageIndexchange and load data methods. **page index** and **page size** is in **filterModel**

```
  pageIndexChanged($event: number) {
    this.pageIndex = $event;
    this.filterModel.pageIndex = this.pageIndex;
    this.loadPage();
  }

  loadPage() {
    this.filterModel.searchTerm = this.searchTerm;
    this.stockHttpService.getList(this.filterModel).subscribe(data => {
        if (this.stockHttpService.checkResponse(data)) {
          this.loading = false;
          this.pageTotal = data.apiResult.dataCount;
          this.listData = data.apiResult.dataResult;
        }
      }
    );
    this.savePageParameter();
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Change the trigger for loadPage. pageIndexChanged gets triggered after you've shown pages and user clicks one of the page numbers.